# Why would a passed-in parameter work in one place but not in another?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a question about passing parameters in Javascript, specifically as values for moment.js to interpret.

I have this function: `function showAll(howlate)`.

I want to pass that howlate parameter to two places in the function
so `function showAll('oneWeekAgo')` is how it's called.

So, this works:

```
$.each(timesheets, function(i, timesheet) {
    if (moment(timesheet.EndDate).isBefore(oneWeekAgo)) {
      $("#demo").append('<span class="' + howlate + '">' + timesheet.UserName + '. </span><br>');
    }
  });
```

but this fails, where I'm trying to pass `howlate` into the moment.js code:

```
$.each(timesheets, function(i, timesheet) {
    if (moment(timesheet.EndDate).isBefore(howlate)) {
      $("#demo").append('<span class="' + howlate + '">' + timesheet.UserName + '. </span><br>');
    }
  })
```

in the `isBefore`, one WeekAgo is a var that represents a moment.js value, `var oneWeekAgo = moment().subtract(7, 'days');`

Is there some syntax that I don't know or understand to pass a parameter into some Javascript and have it be read?

Or am I trying to do too much, having a parameter be replaced by a variable that is replaced by the variable value?

I'm trying to figure out if I've made a syntax error, or tried to do something that can't be done.

Comment: Passing a quoted string is not the same as passing a variable with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're quoting `oneWeekAgo` when you call `showAll`, so it's passing that literal string, not the value of the `oneWeekAgo` variable. Use.

```
showAll(oneWeekAgo);
```

Comment: When I do it without quotes I get ` Uncaught ReferenceError: twoWeeksAgo is not defined`. Does that indicate some other error I might have made?

Comment: That means you never assigned the variable `twoWeeksAgo`. You need to assign it before you can pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: It's assigned inside the function (actually assigned on the 'success' event of an ajax call). Is that not the right place to do it?

Comment: If it's assigned inside the function, why do you need to pass it as an argument to the function? I think you need to update the question to show the whole thing so we can see what you're really trying to do.

Comment: You are correct, though, if I declare and assign the variables outside of the function, it works correctly. Do I need some kind of closure to keep those variables (there are four) from being global?

Comment: You can wrap the whole thing in an IIFE to create an anonymous closure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Accepting this as the answer, though the second comment, beginning "That means..." is as important to the solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your **howLate** variable doesn't point to a valid moment() object.

As per the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/):

> You can check whether the Moment considers the date invalid using moment#isValid. You can check the metrics used by #isValid using moment#parsingFlags, which returns an object.

You can check if a moment is valid by calling

```
moment().isValid();
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to this check, but it returned true.

The howLate parameter is the name of a variable that is a valid moment.js object, like:

`var twoWeeksAgo = moment().subtract(14, 'days');`